# Get nodes from a graph condensation

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

I have an adjacency  matrix `adj` and a cellarray `nodeManes` that contains names that will be given to the graph `G` that will be constructed from `adj`.

So I use `G = digraph(adj,nodeNames);` and I get the following graph :

[image]

Now, I want to find the strongly connected components in `G` and do a graph condensation so I use the following:

```
C = condensation(G);
p2 = plot(C);
```

and get this results : 
[image]

So I have 6 strongly connected components, but my problem is that I lost the node names, I want to get something like: 
[image]

Is that any way to get the nodes names in the result of the condentation?

Answer (score 1):

I think the [official documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/digraph.condensation.html) can take you to the right point:

> **Output Arguments**
>
> **C - Condensation Graph**
>
> Condensation graph, returned as a digraph object. C is a directed
>   acyclic graph (DAG), and is topologically sorted. *The node numbers in
>   C correspond to the bin numbers returned by conncomp.*

Let's take a loot at [conncomp](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.conncomp.html):

> conncomp(G) returns the connected components of graph G as bins. The
>   bin numbers indicate which component each node in the graph belongs to

Look at the examples... I think that if you use `conncomp` on your graph before using the `condensation` function, you will be able to rebuild your node names on your new graph with a little effort.

Comment: the `condensation` fonction already calls the `conncomp` fonction , so no need to do it twice .